# Self Hosting WCF service using app.Config files

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have self hosting WCF service that contains it's own app.Config to expose endpoints required for the service contracts. If the service is started in the programs.cs main method it all works just fine and the metadata is exposed via the browser. However, I created a HostService class based on the ServiceBase class which in the same host library and is instantiated within the program.cs file. The HostService class starts the service and has a timer method to ping other client web services for information.

My question is, when I created the HostService : ServiceBase class and instantiate it from the main(), I have to put a duplicate app.Config file in the Service Library in order for the endpoints to properly exposed and return the metadata/wsdl. I don't want to maintain 2 duplicate app.config files if possible. Currently the host library and service library both require one. Is there a way to only have just one w/ the host that could be used for both? Sorry for the dumb question, but I'm new to WCF =)

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args){
  var service = new HostService(); 
  service.StartHostService(args);   
}
```

HostService.cs

```
public partial class HostService : ServiceBase
{
    internal void StartHostService(string[] args)
    {
        this.OnStart(args);
        Console.ReadLine();
        this.OnStop();
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no. There must be two configs, one for the client that consumes the WCF and one for the server that exposes that communication methods with the WCF.

In order for your client to work, your config must be set with [Client Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/client-configuration)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<configuration>  
  <system.serviceModel>  
        <client>  
          <endpoint  
            name="endpoint1"  
            address="http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service.svc"  
            binding="wsHttpBinding"  
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHello"  
            behaviorConfiguration="IHello_Behavior"  
            contract="IHello" >  

            <metadata>  
              <wsdlImporters>  
                <extension  
                  type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.WsdlDocumentationImporter, WsdlDocumentation"/>  
              </wsdlImporters>  
            </metadata>  

            <identity>  
              <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost" />  
            </identity>  
          </endpoint>  
// Add another endpoint by adding another <endpoint> element.  
          <endpoint  
            name="endpoint2">  
           //Configure another endpoint here.  
          </endpoint>  
        </client>  

//The bindings section references by the bindingConfiguration endpoint attribute.  
    <bindings>  
      <wsHttpBinding>  
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IHello"   
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"   
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard">  
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"/>  
          <reliableSession ordered="true"   
                           enabled="false" />  
          <security mode="Message">  
           //Security settings go here.  
          </security>  
        </binding>  
        <binding name="Another Binding"  
        //Configure this binding here.  
        </binding>  
          </wsHttpBinding>  
        </bindings>  

//The behavior section references by the behaviorConfiguration endpoint attribute.  
        <behaviors>  
            <endpointBehaviors>  
                <behavior name=" IHello_Behavior ">  
                    <clientVia />  
                </behavior>  
            </endpointBehaviors>  
        </behaviors>  

    </system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```

**notice the `<client>` tag specifying how the client must call the WCF.**

and with [Server Config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-services-using-configuration-files):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<configuration>  
 <system.serviceModel>  
  <bindings>  
    <basicHttpBinding>  
     <binding name="myBindingConfiguration1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" />  
     <binding name="myBindingConfiguration2" closeTimeout="00:02:00" />  
     <binding closeTimeout="00:03:00" />  <!—- Default binding for basicHttpBinding -->  
    </basicHttpBinding>  
     </bindings>  
     <services>  
      <service name="MyNamespace.myServiceType">  
       <endpoint   
          address="myAddress" binding="basicHttpBinding"   
          bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration1"  
          contract="MyContract"  />  
       <endpoint   
          address="myAddress2" binding="basicHttpBinding"   
          bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration2"  
          contract="MyContract" />  
       <endpoint   
          address="myAddress3" binding="basicHttpBinding"   
          contract="MyContract" />  
       </service>  
      </services>  
    </system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```

**Notice there is no `<client>` tag here.**

Comment: Perfect, thanks for so much. My implementation is a self hosting service and not an IIS type service w/ a .svc service file, does that matter? Will the client tag still work for both types of implementations? I think if it's a IIS type there would be Web.Config on the .scv service side and not an App.config, is that correct?

Comment: Also, What's strange is, if I start the service within the Program.cs main method, I don't need the App.Config on the service side since it exposes the endpoints and works fine, it's just when I create a serviceBase type class on the host side which starts the service called from the main() that it does. Why is any different do you think?

Comment: that's true, because the client must have both client and service tag :) the client must know which endpoints to use.